# How to implement an auto animation view like UIActivityIndicatorView?

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I need some view like this: when it created by code or .xib, it will automatically play a specific animation and never ending.
For example, YGView, a subclass of UIView, it should transform its background between yellow and green. I know this code can implement the animation:

```
self.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[UIView animateWithDuration:3
                      delay:0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat|UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse|UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     self.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
                 }
                 completion:NULL];
```

, but where should I place this code?

Comment: What specific animation do you have in mind? There's no one technique that is correct for every case.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the UIActivityIndicator. Have a look here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1vWpUwz_xy4